# Outlook - collapsed icon next to removed items without having subfolders

Tags: windows-8.1, exchange-2010, microsoft-outlook-2016

I often create temporary folders, which I delete when not needed anymore. I used to do a soft delete (press delete or right-click < remove). But everytime I did that, it ended up in removed items with an expand icon next to that folder. Since I really don't need the folder, I started to shift-delete which removed the folder completely from the treeview.

Since a few months, everytime I launch outlook, I'm getting an "expand folder" icon next to removed items (= verwijderde items). Whenever I expand said folder, nothing would expand and the icon would disappear.

[image: icon next to "verwijderd items"]

The program works without problem, but I'd like to know if anyone experienced said behavior too and what would cause this (a hidden removed folder,...).

Things I tried so far:

- Create a new profile
- repair office
- Empty the removed items folder

The behavior still persist.

Comment: What account type do you use (Exchange/POP3/IMAP/...)?

Comment: @thims added tag

Comment: If you open your mailbox in OWA, what do you see in Deleted Items?